# MySQL - Display multiple rows in one field (tables with inner joins)q

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join, group-concat

I have a mysql database with 3 tables, one table is called fixturechannels, one is called footballfixtures, and one is called satellite.

Basically the satellite table contains information about satellite channels (name, country, channelid), footballfixtures contains (matchid, hometeam, awayteam, competition....), and fixturechannels is a table containing (matchid, and channelid, these are linked by foriegn keys from the satellite and footballfixtures table respectively).

Below are further details on the tables:

[tablelayouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27fnS.png)

I used the following query below, and it worked, I was able to echo the details I need from the table

```
"SELECT * FROM fixturechannels INNER JOIN footballfixtures ON fixturechannels.matchid=footballfixtures.matchid INNER JOIN satellite ON fixturechannels.channelid=satellite.channelid";
```

The code used for echoing the details is:

```
 <tbody><tr>
            <th>Match ID</th>
            <th>Home Team</th>
            <th>Away Team</th>
            <th>Competition</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Channel ID</th>
            <th>Channel Name</th>


                </tr>
                <?php foreach ($results as $res) { ?>
                <tr>
               <td><?php echo $res["matchid"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $res["hometeam"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $res["awayteam"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $res["competition"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $res["date"]; ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $res["time"]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $res["channelid"]; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $res["name"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
```

My issue is that the match details are displayed twice
as there are two channels listed as showing the same match (see image)

[incorrectoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxMgl.png)

**my desired output is to have the details for each match to be shown once, and the names of multiple channels showing the matches to be displayed in the channel name column (no multiple rows)**

I tried using GROUP_CONCAT, but didn't have success, I tried GROUP_CONCAT as I know it is not recommended to have multiple values per field in MYSQL.

Many Thanks to anyone who can provide assistance or guidance.

Comment: please post tables as text in your questio

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51662/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding a group_by on HOME TEAM, AWAY TEAM and Competition along with  GROUP_CONCAT of channels should work!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I tried this code, but got a syntax error, unexpected 'GROUP' (T_STRING) i tried the code `"SELECT * 
 GROUP_CONCAT(channelid)
FROM fixturechannels 
INNER JOIN footballfixtures
ON fixturechannels.matchid=footballfixtures.matchid
INNER JOIN satellite ON fixturechannels.channelid=satellite.channelid"
GROUP BY hometeam, awayteam, competition;  `   I guess I have done this group_concat incorrectly

Comment: U need to remove '*'   "SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(channelid) FROM fixturechannels INNER JOIN footballfixtures ON fixturechannels.matchid=footballfixtures.matchid INNER JOIN satellite ON fixturechannels.channelid=satellite.channelid" GROUP BY hometeam, awayteam, competition;

Comment: thanks, I got no errors, but none of the data is display anymore on the site, mustn't be an error in the query, but it must not be retrieving the information correctly.

Comment: the sql actually looks ok, as I get my results with no problems in sqlfiddle, must be something wrong with my echo code into the tables?

Comment: You need to fetch all details in the select along with GROUP_CONCAT(channelid) .. GROUP_CONCAT(channelid), matchid, hometeam etc